# how to deserialize unknown named array json using gson

Tags: java, json, gson

The json looks like this :

```
"hour_totals": {
      "382423": {
        "imp": 126,
        "clk": 1,
        "spend": "$0.03",
        "conv": 0,
        "cpm": "$0.22",
        "cpc": "$0.03",
        "ctr": "0.79%",
        "cpa": "$Inf"
      },
      "382424": {
        "imp": 209,
        "clk": 1,
        "spend": "$0.05",
        "conv": 0,
        "cpm": "$0.23",
        "cpc": "$0.05",
        "ctr": "0.48%",
        "cpa": "$Inf"
      }}
```

I read more than 20 answers, but unable to find how to deserialize such a structure, please help on what would the class look like since the hour is not a fixed string.

Comment: I don't think a JSON to Java Object library would work with JSON like this automatically. What it looks like you want is to store the hour nodes as a Map<String,HourDetailObject> but to do this I think you are just going to have to iterate over each node kind of like how people used to read XML

Comment: @JasonSperske thanks, I just thought the same and it worked. FYI `google-gson` was able to handle this type of json.

Comment: @coding you should add your final code as an answer to your own question so people can vote it up.

Comment: @JasonSperske: Gson can parse it assuming that string posted in question is transformed into a valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse this JSON with Gson you need two steps.

1. Define this classes:

   ```
   public class Total {

      Map<String, HourData> hour_totals;

      @Override
      public String toString() {
         return "Total [hour_totals=" + hour_totals + "]";
      }

   }
   ```

   where `HourData` is

   ```
   public class HourData {

      Integer imp;
      Integer clk;
      String spend;
      Integer conv;
      String cpm;
      String cpc;
      String cpa;

      @Override
      public String toString() {
         return "HourData [imp=" + imp + ", clk=" + clk + ", spend=" + spend
               + ", conv=" + conv + ", cpm=" + cpm + ", cpc=" + cpc + ", cpa="
               + cpa + "]";
      }

    }
   ```
2. Hack a bit your "Json string" since it's not a valid Json (see more details below). You just need to add braces like this code:

   ```
   public class Q19201300 {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         String json = "\"hour_totals\": {  "
                 + "  \"382423\": {                 "
                 + "  \"imp\": 126,                 "
                 + "  \"clk\": 1,                   "
                 + "  \"spend\": \"$0.03\",         "
                 + "  \"conv\": 0,                  "
                 + "  \"cpm\": \"$0.22\",           "
                 + "  \"cpc\": \"$0.03\",           "
                 + "  \"ctr\": \"0.79%\",           "
                 + "  \"cpa\": \"$Inf\"             "
                 + "},                              "
                 + "\"382424\": {                   "
                 + "  \"imp\": 209,                 "
                 + "  \"clk\": 1,                   "
                 + "  \"spend\": \"$0.05\",         "
                 + "  \"conv\": 0,                  "
                 + "  \"cpm\": \"$0.23\",           "
                 + "  \"cpc\": \"$0.05\",           "
                 + "  \"ctr\": \"0.48%\",           "
                 + "  \"cpa\": \"$Inf\"             "
                 + "}}                              ";

         Total t = new Gson().fromJson("{" + json + "}", Total.class);

         System.out.println(t);

     }
   }
   ```

This will give you:

> Total [hour_totals={382423=HourData [imp=126, clk=1, spend=$0.03,
>   conv=0, cpm=$0.22, cpc=$0.03, cpa=$Inf], 382424=HourData [imp=209,
>   clk=1, spend=$0.05, conv=0, cpm=$0.23, cpc=$0.05, cpa=$Inf]}]

About your string. From JSON official grammar (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt):

> 1. JSON Grammar
>
>    A JSON text is a sequence of tokens.  The set of tokens includes
>      six    structural characters, strings, numbers, and three literal
>      names.
>
>    A JSON text is a serialized object or array.